# Which data visualization techniques to use to analyse data while solving a classification problem?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, data-visualization, data-science

I am solving a classification problem and I cannot find a good visualization method to analyse my data. Usually while dealing with prediction problems I use barplot, distplot, scatterplot, linegraph,etc. I want to know some common data visualization techniques for classification problems.

Comment: what KPI's you want to visualize ?

Comment: the target variable is binary and the features are categorical

Comment: I think using FacetGrid from seaborn can help. But any other ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi guys I figured that countplot is the the equivalent of histogram https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html

[Example of countplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHCJo.png)
[Example of catplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGQ7P.png)

Update : catplot is actually the combination of FacetGrid and countplot.
So if  you want to do something simple then countplot will do the work for you but if you want grids then use catplot.